# Global variable works in three consecutive switch functions but not in the 4th (is not defined)

Tags: javascript

I've got 4 switch statements. I am using the same global variable in all of them. The first 3 work, but the 4th doesn't. The 4th is written directly below the the previous three, so it's not a problem or scope or some such. It won't even alert the value (console log will say that the varaible is not defined).

Does anyone have any idea why that would be? I can post the code, but there's really quite a lot of it and I don't want to drown you in useless info.

Thank you, D.

The part where global is working (and directly above the code which doesn't work).

```
function emShowError() {
    switch (global){
        case "sl":
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Prosim vnesite svoj elektronski naslov.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Prosim vnesite veljaven elektronski naslov.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
            break;
        case "en":
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address EN.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address EN.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
            break;
        case "de":
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address DE.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address DE.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
            break;
        case "it":
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address IT.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address IT.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
            break;
        case "hr":
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address HR.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address HR.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
            break;
        case "ru":
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address RU.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address RU.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
            break;
        default:
            if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
                emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address.';
            } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address.';
            }
            emailError.className = 'error active';
    }
};
```

The part where the global variable (called global) is not defined.

```
alert(global);

(function(){
    switch (global){
        case "sl":
            confirm('SI-Do you accept our private policy which can be found <a href="#">here</a>?')
                if(false){
                    window.close()
                }
        case "en":
            confirm('EN-Do you accept our private policy which can be found <a href="#">here</a>?')
                if(false){
                    window.close()
                }
        case "de":
            confirm('DE-Do you accept our private policy which can be found <a href="#">here</a>?')
                if(false){
                    window.close()
                }
        case "it":
            confirm('IT-Do you accept our private policy which can be found <a href="#">here</a>?')
                if(false){
                    window.close()
                }
        case "hr":
            confirm('HR-Do you accept our private policy which can be found <a href="#">here</a>?')
                if(false){
                    window.close()
                }
        case "ru":
            confirm('RU-Do you accept our private policy which can be found <a href="#">here</a>?')
                if(false){
                    window.close()
                }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The second code block is an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression), so it is immediately executed on load, and has a private scope. Variables declared in there are invisible from outside.

Where is `global` declared?

Comment: global is delcared a in the 1st js file (called first in html). This code (the last switch, which isn't working) is the last piece of code in the last js file called in the html.

Comment: I mean, it's wierd. it works fine in the first three switches, but if I try to alert(global); anywhere in the code it says not defined (even if I call it before the 3rd switch statement).

Comment: https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6